# how to get if request got basic_ack or basic_nack in pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

For example I have a `consumer` and a `producer`.

In producer, I publish some data for the consumer.

And in consumer, I do some stuff and I can ack or reject the request.

How can I find out in `producer.py` that my request got `basic_ack` or `basic_reject`.

I couldn't find any methods to do some stuff on reject in producer.

Does anybody knows how can I do some stuff in `producer` on `basic_ack`, `basic_nack` or `basic_reject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This is not limited to Pika, but how queuing systems work. Your consumer would have to send a message back to RabbitMQ that the producer would then receive.